# Expression Engine- show default entry if url_title not present in url

Tags: url, title, expressionengine

```
{exp:channel:entries dynamic="yes" limit="1"}
   // some code
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

Dynamic is set to on, so that it will display the entry whose url_title is present as the last segment of the url. All working fine.

I also have an index page (as a channel entry), whose url_title is 'index_page'. But I want this page to appear by default without this last url segment having to be present. Is there a way to do something like:

```
{exp:channel:entries dynamic="yes" default_url_title="index_page" limit="1"}
  // some code
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

Spent the last hour googling this to no avail!

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than using embeds (as they slow ExpressionEngine down (http://www.sidd3.com/10-tips-to-optimize-expressionengine-website-for-better-performance/), an alternate approach is using URL segments.

For example if the url_title you're using is in segment_2 you could do the below:

```
{if segment_2 == ""}

    <!-- So this is your default index page -->
    {exp:channel:entries dynamic="no" url_title="index_page"}
        // some code
    {/exp:channel:entries}

{if:else}

    <!-- And this is all the other pages -->
    {exp:channel:entries dynamic="yes" limit="1"}
    // some code
    {/exp:channel:entries}

{/if}
```

In the else clause I'd prefer to still manually parse the url_title parameter as url_title="{segment_2}"... but that's just me.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, James. Sorry for the late reply. Quite a long winded way of doing it... It really seems EE needs to have a 'default url_title' parameter to be used in conjunction with dynamic=yes as a fall back for when the relevant URL segment is missing...thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use embeds?

1st Template (this captures your normal pages via url_title:

```
{exp:channel:entries dynamic="yes" require_entry="yes" limit="1"}
    {if no_results}
        {embed:template-group/template}
    {/if}

   // some code
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

2nd template - template-group/template (this captures the index_page one):

```
{exp:channel:entries dynamic="no" url_title="index_page"}
   // some code
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
{if segment_2 == ""}
    <!-- So this is your default index page -->
    {exp:channel:entries dynamic="no" url_title="index_page" limit="1"}
{if:else}
    <!-- And this is all the other pages -->
    {exp:channel:entries dynamic="yes" limit="1"}
{/if}

    // some code
{/exp:channel:entries}
```